# SSSR Parameters changing position in Preview Mode

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

I am developing the SSRS report using the Target Server version SQL Server 2008 R2, 2012 or 2014. It was SQL Server 2016 before. So The issue is that when i preview the report , my parameters list is changing its position. For example, In design mode, if i have 3 rows and each row has 3 parameters defined when i preview the report, the 3rd column parameters are adding up to 1st and 2nd column. I dont know why this behaviour. If i run the report using the TargetServerVersion 2016 then parameters displayed properly in Preview report.

any pointers for this issue. I searched on internet but no luck.

Comment: I'm not certain but I think parameter layout is only supported in 2016 onwards

Comment: Adjusting parameter position were added only in 2016 onwards. So if target server is 2008, you cannot move or reposition them.. or the server will "rearrange" then to suit.

Comment: Thanks @AlanSchofield and Harry. Do we have any offiical link which corresponds to this. Just for my information.

Comment: @AlanSchofield : If you post this as an answer then i will accept it.

Comment: @Harry: If you add your comment as an answer then i will accept it.

Comment: I'll let @Harry have this one, mine was a guess! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjusting parameter position were added only in 2016 onwards. So if target server is 2008, you cannot move or reposition them.. or the server will "rearrange" then to suit.

Here is the feature list from microsoft:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/what-s-new-in-sql-server-reporting-services-ssrs?view=sql-server-2016

*Custom Parameters Pane: You can now customize the parameters pane. Using the design surface in Report Builder, you can drag a parameter to a specific column and row in the parameters pane. You can add and remove columns to change the layout of the pane.*